# How to write Select If() in Django model object

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

```
Select IF(5>10, true, false);
```

I want to write this using Django model.

Comment: Could you share your model layout, and where you want to use this? Maybe take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/

Comment: Please elaborate more so that I can provide you exact solution
If you you are looking for ternary operator then have a look on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator

Comment: With aggregate ? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/

Answer (score 1):

you can use case when. see example below:

```
YourModel.objects.annotate(
    discount=Case(
        When(field_value__lte=5, then=Value(1)),
        default=Value(0),
        output_field=IntegerField(),
    ),
)
```

you can write case when as you needed. see documentation in this link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/